# I can't update database from python

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have an sql table which i want to update based on a function
this is my code so far:

```
def read(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor2 = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT All [id],[keyword],[result],[status],[createddate] FROM [Table1].[dbo].[aa]")
    index = 1
    cursor.execute("set nocount on")
    for row in cursor:
        s = row[1]
        s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)
        a=do_func(s)
        if a:
            cursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[aa] set status = 'completed', result = 'True' where id ={}".format(index))
        else:
            cursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[aa] set status = 'completed', result = 'False' where id ={}".format(index))
        if index == 10:
            break
        index += 1
```

i get `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.`
I added "set nocount on" but didn't solve i also tried making a second cursor but also didn't solve problem

Comment: what is do_func doing?

Comment: @MEdwin simply returns either True or False

Comment: You have to commit changes with `conn.commit()`.

Comment: Why do you need to append `.format(index)` the SQL query string?

Comment: @vcp i am not sure i just copied the code from youtube, if you have a better idea to do please show some code

Comment: @Ardweaden where do i `commit()` please show some code

Comment: you will need to split the cursor for select and cursor for update, you cannot use both at the same time. And after update, you will need to commit.

Comment: @MEdwin can you show some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, see the code: you will need to split the cursor for select and cursor for update, you cannot use both at the same time. And after update, you will need to commit. Let me know if it works.

```
def read(conn):
    selectcursor = conn.cursor()
    updatecursor = conn.cursor()
    selectcursor.execute("SELECT [id],[keyword],[result],[status],[createddate] FROM [Table1].[dbo].[aa]")
    index = 1
    result = selectcursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        s = row[1]
        s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)
        a=do_func(s)
        if a:
            updatecursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[aa] set status = 'completed', result = 'True' where id ={}".format(index))
            updatecursor.commit()
        else:
            updatecursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[aa] set status = 'completed', result = 'False' where id ={}".format(index))
            updatecursor.commit()
        if index == 10:
            break
        index += 1
        selectcursor.close()
        updatecursor.close()
```

Comment: `updatecursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[a] set status = 'completed', resulturl = 'False' where id ={}".format(index))
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: it seems there is a lock on that table

Comment: what do you mean by Lock ?

Comment: database tables are locked when you are trying to update it, so that only one person can finish the update. so after update, the connection needs to be closed. I have modified the script, have a look.

Comment: the solution is to add cursor.close()

Comment: do you want to go to a discussion chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190826/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-medwin).

Comment: Don't use string formatting to put values into query strings; use parameters. And there's no need to define seperate queries for `a` being `True` or `False`. Just hand in the string representation of `a`'s value. The whole `if a: [...] else: [...]` block should be replaced by `updatecursor.execute("update [Table1].[dbo].[aa] set status = 'completed', result = ? where id = ?", (str(a), index)); updatecursor.commit()`.

Comment: very good suggestion, but he seems to be trying to add a level of logic on the value of a (do_func is created for that)...

Comment: `do_func` returns `True` or `False` according to the OP. It's return value is assigned to `a` and then `a` is used in a condition to solely decide if the table column `result` will be set to either the string `True` or the string `False`. There's no point in having two query strings to do that :) Plus, my main point of critique is the use of `format()`, although I know, that this was taken from the OP's code.